# To start or shutdown a machine in some domain - PUT /domain/x/machine/y or PUT /domain/x/machine?

Tags: json, api, rest, http

I'm trying to design the REST API for starting, stopping, .... (and other actions) some machines in some domains. There are two options, e.g., for stopping,

Approach 1: PUT `/domains/x/machines` with machine name in the body

```
PUT http://myserver.com/api/domains/x/machines HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/json

{ "machine_name": "y", "state": "running" }
```

Approach 2: PUT `/domains/x/machines/y`

```
PUT http://myserver.com/api/domains/x/machines/y HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/json

{ "state": "running" }
```

Which one is more RESTful? The second one may have problem if the machine has an attribute `state` to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

[PUT](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-9.3.4) means something close to "replace the representation of the resource".  In other words, we should expect the body of the PUT request to look like the body of the GET *response*.

---

```
PUT /api/domains/x/machines HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
Content-Type: application/json

{ "machine_name": "y", "state": "running" }
```

That's probably not what the representation of `/api/domains/x/machines` looks like.  Based on the spelling of the resource identifier, that's probably intended to be information about a collection of machines.

```
[
{ "machine_name": "y", "state": "running" }
]
```

That might be right if there were only one machine in the collection; but it should be clear in your mind that if there were five machines described by the resource, and you  were restarting one of them, then all five machines would be described in the PUT request body.

---

```
PUT /api/domains/x/machines/y HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
Content-Type: application/json

{ "state": "running" }
```

Again, the PUT request body should look like the GET response body, so this could make sense if state were the only property included in the representation (in which case, maybe the URI spelling could be improved).

---

If the goal here is to send only a representation of the information that is changing, then the appropriate HTTP message to use is `PATCH`

```
PATCH /api/domains/x/machines/y HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

{ "state": "running" }
```

---

Also, keep in mind that the web was catastrophically successful without much adoption of PUT or PATCH.  [It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

```
POST /api/domains/x/machines/y HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

state=running
```

---

This specific problem was raised by [Tim Bray in 2009](https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2009/03/20/Rest-Casuistry), and there are some very good ideas in the comments.  Of course, there are also some not so good ideas.  To prepare yourself, I suggest that you first take time to review [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=188s)  - make sure you understand what HTTP *is* before you try to apply it to this particular problem.

Comment: Thanks, I may need to use PUT, PATCH, or POST to update, create the resource instead of do the actions on the resource. Should the logic in the code to decide what to do base on some convention? I saw some people adding action to the URL, e.g. `POST /resource/x/start`, but someone said this is not RESTful.

Comment: "in which case, maybe the URI spelling could be improved", how to improve the URI spelling? The machines have a lot of other properties. Maybe PATCH is more appropriate.